# Cómo utilizar DISTINCT ON (nombre_columna) y luego combinar los resultados con todos los registros de otra tabla

Tags: postgresql, distinct

Estoy utilizando PostgreSQL 12. Tengo las tablas sitios y clase_valor. Para cada sitio deseo determinar las clases que existen y su máximo valor. Luego sumar esos valores y obtener los resultados para todos los sitios, no solo para aquellos donde existe alguna clase.

```
CREATE TABLE public.sitios
(
    id_sitio integer NOT NULL,
    nombre_sitio character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT sitios_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_sitio)
);

INSERT INTO public.sitios (id_sitio,nombre_sitio) VALUES
(1,'sitio1'),
(2,'sitio2'),
(3,'sitio3'),
(4,'sitio4'),
(5,'sitio5'),
(6,'sitio6'),
(7,'sitio7'),
(8,'sitio8'),
(9,'sitio9'),
(10,'sitio10'),
(11,'sitio11'),
(12,'sitio12');

CREATE TABLE public.clase_valor
(
    id_cv integer NOT NULL,
    id_sitio integer NOT NULL,
    clase character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    valor numeric(2,1),
    CONSTRAINT clase_valor_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_cv),
    CONSTRAINT sitios_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_sitio)
        REFERENCES public.sitios (id_sitio) MATCH FULL
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE SET NULL
);

INSERT INTO public.clase_valor (id_cv,id_sitio,clase,valor) VALUES
(1,1,'clase_a',1.0),
(2,2,'clase_b',0.5),
(3,1,'clase_c',0.0),
(4,1,'clase_a',1.0),
(5,4,'clase_d',0.5),
(6,2,'clase_d',0.5),
(7,1,'clase_c',0.0),
(8,4,'clase_a',1.0),
(9,2,'clase_c',0.0);
```

Quiero obtener para cada sitio el valor máximo determinado como la suma de los valores para cada clase, tomando en considerando que si en un sitio hay varias clases de un mismo tipo solo la tengo en cuenta una vez. Probé con esta vista:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.final_val
 AS
 WITH clasea AS (
         SELECT DISTINCT ON (cv.id_sitio) cv.id_sitio AS codigo1,
            cv.valor AS valor1
           FROM public.clase_valor cv
          WHERE cv.clase = 'clase_a'
          ORDER BY cv.id_sitio, cv.valor DESC
        ), clasebd AS (                                         ---clase_b y clase_d se consideran similares
         SELECT DISTINCT ON (cv.id_sitio) cv.id_sitio AS codigo2,
            cv.valor AS valor2
           FROM public.clase_valor cv
          WHERE cv.clase IN ('clase_b','clase_d')
          ORDER BY cv.id_sitio, cv.valor DESC
        ), clasec AS (
         SELECT DISTINCT ON (cv.id_sitio) cv.id_sitio AS codigo3,
            cv.valor AS valor3
           FROM public.clase_valor cv
          WHERE cv.clase = 'clase_c'
          ORDER BY cv.id_sitio, cv.valor DESC
        )
 SELECT s.id_sitio,
    s.nombre_sitio,
    valor1+valor2+valor3 AS maxval
   FROM public.sitios s, clasea, clasebd, clasec;
```

Pero me arroja 96 registros y solo necesito 12 (uno por sitio), tal como muestra la siguiente tabla. Aquí solo necesito id_sitio, nombre_sitio y max_val.

```
id_sitio    nombre_sitio     clasea  clasebd    clasec   maxval
1           sitio1              1.0              0.0        1.0
2           sitio2                      0.5      0.0        0.5
3           sitio3                                          0.0
4           sitio4              1.0     0.5                 1.5
5           sitio5                                          0.0
6           sitio6                                          0.0
7           sitio7                                          0.0
8           sitio8                                          0.0
9           sitio9                                          0.0
10          sitio10                                         0.0
11          sitio11                                         0.0
12          sitio12                                         0.0
```

Les agradezco cualquier sugerencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta query retorna el resultado que vos esperas:

```
SELECT id_sitio, nombre_sitio, max(clase_a) AS clasea, max(clase_bd) AS clacebd, max(clase_c) AS clasec,
  coalesce(max(clase_a), 0) + coalesce(max(clase_bd), 0) + coalesce(max(clase_c), 0) AS maxval

FROM (
      SELECT s.id_sitio, s.nombre_sitio,
        CASE WHEN clase = 'clase_a' THEN valor END AS clase_a,
        CASE WHEN clase = 'clase_b' OR clase ='clase_d'  THEN valor END AS clase_bd,
        CASE WHEN clase = 'clase_c' THEN valor END AS clase_c
      FROM sitios s
      LEFT JOIN clase_valor c ON c.id_sitio = s.id_sitio
) AS aux

GROUP BY id_sitio, nombre_sitio
ORDER BY id_sitio
```

Comment: No responde exactamente la pregunta porque no utiliza el DISTINCT ON, pero la acepto porque resuelve el problema, además lo hace en una forma muy comprensible. Solo tuve que sustituir 0 por 0.0 dentro de COALESCE. Muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada @Jorge! Me alegra que te haya resultado util mi query.